# redirect with sleep php - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How do I run sleep when someone enters the view /logo?

I want that when someone enters the url / logo they are redirected in 5 seconds to another url

```
 public function publi () {
     
    if (sleep(5)) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return  view('store.logo');

 }
```

help pls

Comment: Do you need a page to open and then redirect?
If yes, then use in view
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript in your view to redirect after 5 seconds (5000ms).

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```